# Requirements for initiating a print on a 3D printer via USB

Tags: octoprint, 3d-printing

I thought it would be fun to implement a rudimentary version of Octoprint that can receive a gcode file and initiate a print on my Prusa i3.

What are the requirements for initiating a print on a 3D printer via USB?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [pySerial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) library in Python to send raw [G-Code](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/articles/3d-printing-gcode-tutorial/) to the `/dev/ttyWhereverYourPrinterIs` serial device. Most printers specify their baud rate in their UI, or user's manual. My printer says its USB baud rate is 115200.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Gina Häußge](https://www.patreon.com/posts/25655021?cid=21224458):

> If you are only targeting a very specific printer with a very specific firmware variant: serial connection and then read up on https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code. It becomes a horrible nightmare to implement and maintain though when you take the thousands of firmware variants out there into account, so beware.